# Duplicate symbols for architecture i386. Checked all answers. Nothing helped

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am using facebook sdk for login in a swift app. The sdk is working fine when I test on a device but on simulator it shows some duplicate symbols. I have checked compiled sources in build phases. There are no duplicate entries.

I have included fbsdkloginkit and fbsdkcorekit in the project.

**This is the begining of the error message:**

> Ld
>   /Users/asidhu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company.Social-dznvauauyeazijdnqbzqwtrnciqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Company.Social.app/Company.Social
>   normal i386
>       cd /Users/asidhu/Desktop/Projects/Company.Social
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk
>   -L/Users/asidhu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company.Social-dznvauauyeazijdnqbzqwtrnciqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/asidhu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company.Social-dznvauauyeazijdnqbzqwtrnciqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/asidhu/Desktop/Projects/Company.Social -F/Users/asidhu/Downloads/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910 -filelist /Users/asidhu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company.Social-dznvauauyeazijdnqbzqwtrnciqj/Build/Intermediates/Company.Social.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Company.Social.build/Objects-normal/i386/Company.Social.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
>   -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/asidhu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company.Social-dznvauauyeazijdnqbzqwtrnciqj/Build/Intermediates/Company.Social.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Company.Social.build/Objects-normal/i386/Company_Social.swiftmodule
>   -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -framework StoreKit -framework UIKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreText -framework
>   CoreGraphics -framework CoreMotion -framework GoogleSignIn -framework
>   CoreLocation -framework Foundation -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework
>   AssetsLibrary -framework AddressBook -Xlinker -dependency_info
>   -Xlinker /Users/asidhu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company.Social-dznvauauyeazijdnqbzqwtrnciqj/Build/Intermediates/Company.Social.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Company.Social.build/Objects-normal/i386/Company.Social_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/asidhu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company.Social-dznvauauyeazijdnqbzqwtrnciqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Company.Social.app/Company.Social
>
> duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
>       /Users/asidhu/Downloads/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginButton.o)
>       /Users/asidhu/Downloads/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginCompletion.o)
>   duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
>       /Users/asidhu/Downloads/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/

**This is the end of the error message:**

> FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginButton.o)
>       /Users/asidhu/Downloads/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKMaleSilhouetteIcon.o)
>   ld: 154 duplicate symbols for architecture i386 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You are importing twice FBSDKCoreKit.framework, check your build settings (project/target)

Comment: @JefferyThomas : I have checked it. It is added once in the target/build phases

Comment: @user3730935 can you please check this in your project directory?

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA : I have checked it in the project directory also. No duplicate files.

Comment: so can you try to remove refrence from your project and re add your framework hope this helps you.

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA : Done a couple of times. Removing and re adding. No hope. Its running fine on devices.

Comment: just try to remove from directory also and re add  it it will work for  me when i had this type error please try at once. i have no other answer sorry.

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA : Thanks for your valuable time. It didn't work. I tried it number of times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90612/discussion-between-jay-raparka-and-user3730935).

Comment: anybody get any solution for it?

Comment: I still stuck at the point bro!!